# Wrong Page Numbering using hepthesis

Tags: page-numbering, thesis, hepthesis

I am using the `hepthesis` document class, which is built on `scrbook`, and it produces incorrect page numbering for the following code:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{hepthesis}
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
\end{frontmatter}

\begin{mainmatter}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    Chapter 1 Text.
    \begin{figure}
        Empty Figure
        \caption{My Empty Figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{mainmatter}

\end{document}
```

The list of figures ends up on page 1 not page iii. If I add `\newpage`, `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` then the list of figures is page iii but page 1 is blank. How do I keep the list of figures numbered as with the rest of the front matter without introducing superfluous blank pages?

Comment: It seems that the `hepthesis` class is a bit buggy... I get a blank first page, too. BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Changing `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` into environments is a big mistake made by the `hepthesis` class. This may have nasty effects on memory usage (stack size overflow).

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but we found a (hacky) fix to this problem at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170231/page-numbering-transition-from-frontmatter-to-mainmatter-going-wrong/ Hope its still useful