# Page numbering transition from frontmatter to mainmatter going wrong

Tags: page-numbering, thesis, hepthesis

My problem is already stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141742/wrong-page-numbering-using-hepthesis), but I don't have enough reputation to comment on it :-/ I want to know if there are any fixes or solutions to the problem with the hepthesis class?

The last page of the table of contents is numbered with arabic numerals rather than roman numerals. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{hepthesis}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frontmatter}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{frontmatter}

  \begin{mainmatter}
    \chapter{Introduction}
      lalala
  \end{mainmatter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't get your MWE to compile. It complains about a runaway argument... See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141742/39222 for criticism of `hepthesis`...

Comment: I just realised that's the page you linked to. But I think the important point there may be the criticism rather than the problem statement. Must you use `hepthesis`? It sounds as if it may be a painful experience.

Comment: Ha! It's a bit too late for that. I've mostly finished writing the thesis, and I thought it'd be simple to fix such a page numbering issue.

Comment: Well I can't even compile your MWE so the page numbering issue seems relatively minor!

Comment: usually, it's just `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, not a `\begin ... \end` construction.  in any event, try adding `\newpage` after `\tableofcontents` and that should take care of the problem.

Comment: @cfr Ok, thanks for trying (it compiles for me, so difficult for me to help you)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The `frontmatter` and `mainmatter` environments are part of the `hepthesis` class. I tried the `newpage` idea already, and it does indeed make the last ToC page have roman numbering. Unfortunately, it creates a new page which has a ToC header and is otherwise blank! Not great.

Comment: `\clearpage` rather than `\newpage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may or may not work, but it's too complicated for a comment.

`hepthesis.cls` loads `scrbook.cls`.

`scrbook.cls` defines `\mainmatter` thus:

```
\newcommand*\mainmatter{%
  \if@twoside\cleardoubleoddpage\else\clearpage\fi
  \@mainmattertrue\pagenumbering{arabic}%
}
```

`hepthesis.cls` does some fancy tinkering with `\mainmatter`:

```
%% Environment for the thesis main body
\let\@oldmainmatter\mainmatter
\specialcomment{mainmatter}{%
  %\@oldmainmatter%
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
  \adjustwidth{\@mainmatterextramargin}{\@mainmatterextramargin}%
  \begin{\@mainmatterspacing}%
}{%
  \end{\@mainmatterspacing}%
  \endadjustwidth%
  \ignorespacesafterend%
}
```

it seems to me that since `\mainmatter` = `\@oldmainmatter` already sets the page
numbering to `\arabic`, it should be possible to just comment out the line

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}%
```

in the `hepthesis` definition since it should already be there, with better timing.

(i haven't tried this, so it's not guaranteed, but i think it's a reasonable analysis.
and if it *doesn't* work, i'll be happy to delete this answer.)

Comment: Thank you! This was an important step! Once I commented out that line, I then had to add `\cleardoublepage` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` at the start of the `mainmatter` environment in my document. This has solved the problem though (albeit in a hacky way)

Comment: I am confused: Where is the command `\specialcomment` from? `\@oldmainmatter` is already commented (???).

Comment: Also confused though for different reasons. @Speravir `\specialcomment` is, I think, from the `comment` package and `\@oldmainmatter` is, indeed, already commented in `hepthesis.cls`. But I don't understand where `\mainmatter = \@oldmainmatter` comes in/from...

Comment: @cfr: For the latest: I think this is just a statement/conclusion of Barbara.

Comment: I'm the author of hepthesis, so am interested in this although coming to it a bit late. More on that in a moment.

Does anyone have an explanation of why the "timing" of the switch to arabic numbering within the env/comment goes wrong? Would re-ordering it (after a \clearpage?) help? Maybe because of how specialcomment works: I see in its manual that it does some finicky cutting of verbatim chunks of source to .cut files, which sounds fragile. Redefining it as an environment rather than a special comment might help... thoughts?

Comment: I'll also just note that the proposed solution isn't quite right, since the call to \@oldmainmatter is commented out in the mainmatter special comment defn. In fact note that the content of the mainmatter 1st block pretty much *is* the same as the scrbook \mainmatter definition: that's not an accident. Using \@oldmainmatter is commented out because it didn't work either... maybe (again) because of the odd way that specialcomment works.  I guess this is why David had to re-add \pagenumbering{arabic} it and a \clear(double)page in his document, where it worked because outside the comment block.

Comment: Final comment for context: I wrote this package ~10 years ago for my own PhD thesis and have only slightly tinkered with it since... patches would be very welcome but I'm not actively developing or maintaining it. A new (co-)maintainer would be welcome if there is interest!

Comment: @andybuckley. First of all nice template, I'm using it for my thesis at the moment and I like the style. But I didn't really get the fix. I downloaded the `cls` file from ctan, I commented the `\pagenumbering{arabic}` out and instead put it into the main text plus included an `\clearpage` before it. Now the `toc` part looks nice, except that it still adds a page with the heading of toc prior to beginning with the chapters. Could you help me what I missed?

Comment: Hi @magu_, sorry but I didn't set a notification about your comment and I guess it's too late now. Apologies for the delay -- I implemented a fix in August then didn't get time to release it -- but hepthesis 1.5.0 has just been uploaded to CTAN with a fix which at least works for the example.tex doc. It should become available in the next 24 hours or so. Let me know (by email, see package docs) if you have any problems with that.